# vcpkg does not work for google test

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, vcpkg

I installed and integrated latest version of vcpkg:

```
e:\work\vcpkg>vcpkg version
Vcpkg package management program version 0.0.65-692a363701156f1bc319306fbde93fb6748325f6

See LICENSE.txt for license information.

e:\work\vcpkg>vcpkg integrate install
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

All C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.
Linking will be handled automatically.
Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.
```

I installed google test:

```
e:\work\vcpkg>vcpkg list
gtest:x64-windows           1.8              GoogleTest and GoogleMock testing frameworks.
gtest:x86-windows           1.8              GoogleTest and GoogleMock testing frameworks.
```

I included `gtest.h` in my project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
```

It compiles fine, but I have linker errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl testing::InitGoogleTest(int *,char * *)" (?InitGoogleTest@testing@@YAXPEAHPEAPEAD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl testing::UnitTest::Run(void)" (?Run@UnitTest@testing@@QEAAHXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class testing::UnitTest * __cdecl testing::UnitTest::GetInstance(void)" (?GetInstance@UnitTest@testing@@SAPEAV12@XZ)
```

Apparently, Visual Studio does not know it should link with `gtest.lib`. And I cannot understand why. Vcpkg only says that "Linking will be handled automatically." No idea how it is going to do this.

In "Additional Library Dependencies" of my project I can see these inherited values:

```
$(VcpkgRoot)lib
$(VcpkgRoot)lib\manual-link
```

And `$(VcpkgRoot)` is resolved to `e:\work\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\`. So it seems like integration was successful. But how Visual Studio knows it should link with `gtest.lib`?

Note that if I add `gtest.lib` to "Additional Dependencies" manually, all works fine, and `gtest.dll` is automatically copied to output directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the autolinking behavior has been intentionally disabled for `gtest`, see [vcpkg issue #306](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/306).
Original comment on the issue: [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/457#issuecomment-269094822).

The vcpkg implementation requires manual linking because Google Test can redefine `main()`, and the gtest functionality is duplicated in all of the four separate library files.
[Official documentation](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/integration/#integrate-command).

**The required per project configuration:**
In: `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Input` > `Additional Dependencies`
For release-builds:

```
$(VcpkgRoot)lib\manual-link\gtest_main.lib
```

For debug-builds:

```
$(VcpkgRoot)debug\lib\manual-link\gtest_main.lib
```

If you want to create your own custom main(), replace `gtest_main.lib` with `gtest.lib`.
If you want to use gmock, you can replace it with `gmock_main.lib` or `gmock.lib`.

Comment: So the recommended way to link `gtest` is as I did it: actually add it to "Additional Dependencies", right?

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But may be something was changed since moment of the answer, because currently names of debug libraries ends with 'd' - "gtestd.lib" and "gtest_maind.lib".

Comment: Yes, it has, since 2018-03-12, see PR #3013.
And since 2018-11-14 (PR #4220) only the `*_main.lib` versions are in the `manual-link` folders.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I would like to point out what I've found.

You need to link the libs in the manual-link directory, but you need to link them in the right order.
First link gmock_main then gtest_main.
The other way around just results in 0 test.